# issue with $cordovaContacts

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

i'm new in stackoverflow forum and i decide to create this topic to solve a problem wich i'm stuck for 2 weeks.

I have the following :

- Visual Studio Android Emulator
- Ionic 1 project created with the tabs pattern.

I'm trying to use the ngCordova contacts module ( $cordovaContacts ) to retrieve the phone numbers of the contacts. The problem is that there is an error with the "navigator" object. I found that there is not possible to acces the fields of these object ( functions , app , contacts , splashscreen ) so when i call to $cordovaContacts.find(...) it shows the error : "Can not find property find of undefined" . I invested some time debugging and when i use :

```
console.log(navigator);
```

The console shows:

```
[object Object]

services.js (21,15)

CordovaNavigator

_ {_

_ [functions]: ,_

_ proto: { },_

_ app: { },_

_ contacts: { },_

_ splashscreen: { }_

_ }_
```

But when i print **navigator.contacts** object it shows undefined

I also tried to use **navigator.CordovaNavigator** but is also undefined.

This code is called when loading controllers.

I have no idea why it shows that navigator has an atribute contacts and then when i call it it shows UNDEFINED . Maybe i need to stablish some acces rights ??.

I'm really lost so anything you tell me will help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to fetch the contacts on controller load (means, that you don't trigger it manually inside another method or via a timeout / interval), you'll need to wrap it with the ionicPlatform.ready() method, else the plugin isn't ready at that point.

```
ionic.Platform.ready(function(){
    $cordovaContacts.find().then(function(allContacts) {
        $scope.contacts = allContacts;
    });
});
```